# Preferred approach for storing a reference to a file handle/DB handle, etc...?

Tags: haskell

In the Learn You A Haskell book, there is [a todo example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) that uses the `do` notation to assign the `tempName` and `tempHandle`:

```
do
    ...
    (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
```

Which means that `tempName` and `tempHandle` are accessible throughout the function, that means you can do whatever you like in between the `openTempFile` and having to `hClose` at the end. However, as `do` notation is apparently syntactic sugar for `>>=` I'm trying to transform the `do` into bind, and finding it difficult to maintain a reference to `tempHandle`.

With my limited understanding of Haskell, I see a couple of options:

- Store the `tempHandle` in the `where` clause so that it's accessible from the function;
- Pass the `tempHandle` reference in the `>>=` alongside other data that I need in each step of the bind: (`return ("Transformed Data", tempHandle)`!?).

How would you do this? Am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

---

**Edit:** How would I keep a reference to `handle` if you transformed the `do` notation to `>>=` in the following example:

```
main = do
    handle <- openFile "name.txt" (WriteMode)
    putStrLn "Enter your name: "
    name <- getLine
    hPutStr handle name
    hClose handle
```

When transformed to `>>=` how would I reference `handle`?

```
main =
    openFile "name.txt" WriteMode >>
    putStrLn "Enter your name: " >>
    getLine >>=
    (\name -> hPutStr handle?? name) >>
    hClose handle??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do
  (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
  ...
```

is the same as

```
openTempFile "." "temp" >>= \(tempName, tempHandle) ->
...
```

The second one is much harder to read, why would you want to use it ?

To complete your example :

```
main =
    openFile "name.txt" WriteMode >>= \handle ->
    putStrLn "Enter your name: " >>
    getLine >>=
    (\name -> hPutStr handle name) >>
    hClose handle
```

Comment: I was merely wondering if there was a better way. What happens if you wanted to open a file, transform the content a few times using `>>=`, and then write back the text? Do you need to pass the `handle` to each `>>=` or is it preferred to use the `do` notation or `where` clause?

Comment: do notation was exactly invented as syntactic sugar for `>>=`, to make your life easier :)

Comment: That's cool, I just want to understand the `>>=` syntax a little better, as it feels like `do` is hiding things from me. Please see my updated question with a simple, contrived code example.

Comment: Only one `>>=` will provide the handle, the one mentioned in this answer. You will use it in other file operations e.g. `... >>= \(tempName, tempHandle) -> readTheFile tempHandle >>= \content -> writeTheFile tempHandle (frob content) >> hClose tempHandle`. It is easier to read in do notation, but not too bad in bind-notation either.

Comment: Note that the lambda `\(tempName, tempHandle) ->...` ends at the very end of the function, __not__ at the next `>>=`. I guess this is the source of your misunderstanding. In do notation it is the same: every `x <- ...` is in scope until the do block ends.

Answer (score 3):

The direct way to de-sugar the do-notation would be:

```
main =
    openFile "name.txt" (WriteMode) >>= \handle ->
    putStrLn "Enter your name: " >>
    getLine >>= \name ->
    hPutStr handle name >>
    hClose handle
```

Note that the whole thing after `\handle ->` is part of the same function body so `handle` is in scope for all the following expressions.

Comment: Is it common practice in Haskell to indent the `putStrLn` line and onwards to make it clearer that the last 4 lines are part of the anonymous function? As the way you've written it doesn't make it clear that there's an anonymous function, aside from the `->` at the end of the 2nd line.

Comment: In bind-blocks it is fairly common to indent the code as above since otherwise we need to indent more and more. Of course, do blocks are more common. Also common: `forM_ [1..n] $ \i -> do` followed a newline and indented do-block. So, yes, `\x ->` at the very end of the line is quite common. It looked weird the very first time I saw it, but now no longer so. Further, keep in mind that there's no standard indentation in Haskell (like e.g. in Java or Scala).